# from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell import _linear

Tags: tensorflow

Mine is tensor flow v 1.0 and i am getting this error how resolve this error
Error:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named rnn_cell

Thanks 
Pratik goyal

Comment: Please post the code that gives you that error.

Comment: Thanks Allen but it got solved again thank you very much

Comment: @PratikGoyal I am facing the same error. Could you please post the solution?